# Getting <img> svg preserved width / height or viewBox with Javascript (JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a possibility to read a preserved `width` and `height` or `viewBox` values of the `img` with `svg` source file?
I tried something like this but still get `undefined`.

```js
$('img.cart').load(function(){
  console.log($('img.cart').children('svg').attr('viewBox'));
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="cart" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/cartman.svg">
```

Comment: Look again the snippet i have updated the code

Answer (score 0):

By using SVG inside img tag you cannot access the svg attributes mostly try using tag attributes `$('img.cart').css('height'));`

```js
$('img.cart').load(function(){
  console.log($('img.cart').css('height'));
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <img class="cart" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/cartman.svg" height='30px;'>
<img class="cart" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/cartman.svg" height='130px;'>
 <img class="cart" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/cartman.svg">
```

Comment: Thank you, @Joyson. Unfortunately `.css('height')` returns always the height of the `img` but not the real graphic size inside. So when `img` is limited by the container, the graphic is scaled but the w/h values of `img` element are not in the ratio of `svg`.

Comment: But you can limit the height of the svg by setting height to your `img` tag @friedman

Comment: Well... Thank you again but that's not the issue. If I've had already set the height for the tag then getting it would be no point.

The problem is to get the ratio (or height / width) of the svg graphic to position other elements on site.

Comment: did you solve this issue?